# how can I get filenames from h5 file?

Tags: python-3.x, h5py

I have an h5 file that contains multiple images. I would like to know, how can I get the original filename of individual images from the h5 file? The h5 file has keys "image" and "label".

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the schema definition? If so, please share. If not, it's hard to be specific. Fortunately, HDF5 files are self-describing, so your can deduce the schema with a little interrogation. There are at least 3 ways to discover the schema: 1) Use **HDFView** to open and inspect the file; 2) use **h5dump** utility (it's a command line utility that dumps the file schema); 3) write a h5py `visititems()` callable function to do it.

Comment: In `h5py` a file contains groups and/or datasets.  Explore those as you would a nested dictionary.  Each level can also have attributes.  `h5py` docs explain those as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for "Keys". Here is your answer.

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('your_file.h5', 'r') as f:
     print("Keys: %s" %f.keys())
```